# How to redirect from payment gateway to success page using the callback URL in Magento 2.x

Tags: php, magento2, payment-gateway

I had integrated the Razorpay payment gateway in my magento site. It's working absolutely fine in web and mobile browser. But when I try to make the payment using in-app browsers (from Instagram, Facebook) I am facing the blank page issue. So I found the solution that I need to pass the callback URL along with other input parameter to payment gateway. Here I got stuck, what should be the callback URL here? Can anyone help me to resolve this!

Here is my code:

/app/code/Razorpay/Magento/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/razorpay-method.js

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-payment-information',
        'mage/url',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
        'Magento_Ui/js/model/messageList'
    ],
    function (Component, quote, $, ko, additionalValidators, setPaymentInformationAction, url, customer, placeOrderAction, fullScreenLoader, messageList) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Razorpay_Magento/payment/razorpay-form',
                razorpayDataFrameLoaded: false,
                rzp_response: {}
            },
            getMerchantName: function() {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.razorpay.merchant_name;
            },

            getKeyId: function() {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.razorpay.key_id;
            },

            context: function() {
                return this;
            },

            isShowLegend: function() {
                return true;
            },

            getCode: function() {
                return 'razorpay';
            },

            isActive: function() {
                return true;
            },

            isAvailable: function() {
                return this.razorpayDataFrameLoaded;
            },

            handleError: function (error) {
                if (_.isObject(error)) {
                    this.messageContainer.addErrorMessage(error);
                } else {
                    this.messageContainer.addErrorMessage({
                        message: error
                    });
                }
            },

            initObservable: function() {
                var self = this._super();              //Resolves UI Error on Checkout


                if(!self.razorpayDataFrameLoaded) {
                    $.getScript("https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js", function() {
                        self.razorpayDataFrameLoaded = true;
                    });
                }

                return self;
            },

            /**
             * @override
             */
             /** Process Payment */
            preparePayment: function (context, event) {

                if(!additionalValidators.validate()) {   //Resolve checkout aggreement accept error
                    return false;
                }

                var self = this,
                    billing_address,
                    rzp_order_id;

                fullScreenLoader.startLoader();
                this.messageContainer.clear();

                this.amount = quote.totals()['base_grand_total'] * 100;
                billing_address = quote.billingAddress();

                this.user = {
                    name: billing_address.firstname + ' ' + billing_address.lastname,
                    contact: billing_address.telephone,
                };

                if (!customer.isLoggedIn()) {
                    this.user.email = quote.guestEmail;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.user.email = customer.customerData.email;
                }

                this.isPaymentProcessing = $.Deferred();

                $.when(this.isPaymentProcessing).done(
                    function () {
                        self.placeOrder();
                    }
                ).fail(
                    function (result) {
                        self.handleError(result);
                    }
                );

                self.getRzpOrderId();

                return;
            },

            getRzpOrderId: function () {
                var self = this;

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url.build('razorpay/payment/order'),

                    /**
                     * Success callback
                     * @param {Object} response
                     */
                    success: function (response) {
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                        if (response.success) {
                            self.renderIframe(response);
                        } else {
                            self.isPaymentProcessing.reject(response.message);
                        }
                    },

                    /**
                     * Error callback
                     * @param {*} response
                     */
                    error: function (response) {
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                        self.isPaymentProcessing.reject(response.message);
                    }
                });
            },

            renderIframe: function(data) {
                var self = this;

                this.merchant_order_id = data.order_id;

                var options = {
                    key: self.getKeyId(),
                    name: self.getMerchantName(),
                    amount: data.amount,
                    handler: function (data) {
                        self.rzp_response = data;
                        self.placeOrder(data);
                    },
                    order_id: data.rzp_order,
                    modal: {
                        ondismiss: function() {
                            self.isPaymentProcessing.reject("Payment Closed");
                        }
                    },
                    notes: {
                        merchant_order_id: '',
                        merchant_quote_id: data.order_id
                    },
                    prefill: {
                        name: this.user.name,
                        contact: this.user.contact,
                        email: this.user.email
                    },
                    callback_url: url.build('rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information', {}),
                    _: {
                        integration: 'magento',
                        integration_version: data.module_version,
                        integration_parent_version: data.maze_version,
                    }
                };

                if (data.quote_currency !== 'INR')
                {
                    options.display_currency = data.quote_currency;
                    options.display_amount = data.quote_amount;
                }

                this.rzp = new Razorpay(options);

                this.rzp.open();
            },

            getData: function() {
                return {
                    "method": this.item.method,
                    "po_number": null,
                    "additional_data": {
                        rzp_payment_id: this.rzp_response.razorpay_payment_id,
                        order_id: this.merchant_order_id,
                        rzp_signature: this.rzp_response.razorpay_signature
                    }
                };
            }
        });
    }


);
```

In the above code `renderIframe` function will pass the parameter to payment gateway, here I need to pass the callback URL. I tried to set it as `rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information` but got `401 Unauthorised` error. Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing with amazon payment.
As i remember you should act on this part of codes :

```
function () {
   self.placeOrder();
}
```

And how i changed

```
function () {
    $.when(self.placeOrder()).done(
        function () {
           ///redirect;
        }
}
```

But when i tried on the browser, i've still got some wrong cases then i decided to make a workaround by putting an event with jquery :

```
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
    //redirect
});
```

This works right because after all ajaxs are finished we get the order is placed. That is the time to redirect.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your help here. As I mentioned above the redirection flow is working fine in web browser and mobile browser as well. Only the problem is with in-app browser because razorpay payment gateway needs the callback_url to redirect to success page ( as they had mentioned in the doc https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/callback-url/). So what should I give in the place of callbak_url?